# Flutter build error for IOS, Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm trying to build an archive using `flutter build ipa` command but it throws an error

#### Logs

`flutter build ipa`

```
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode archive done.                                         170.1s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    objc[32852]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerRestoreInfoHelper is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f6201eb0) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1069584f8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[32852]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareAggregateRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f6201f00) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106958548). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[32852]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareRequestCreator is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f6201f50) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106958598). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[32852]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABFile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f6201fa0) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x1069585e8). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[32852]: Class AppleTypeCRetimerFirmwareCopier is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f6201ff0) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106958638). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    objc[32852]: Class ATCRTRestoreInfoFTABSubfile is implemented in both /usr/lib/libauthinstall.dylib (0x1f6202040) and
    /Library/Apple/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/MobileDevice (0x106958688). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
    ** ARCHIVE FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
/// lots of warning logs
/// lots of warning logs
    error: the following command failed with exit code 0 but produced no further
    output
    CompileC
    /Users/sajad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ecujwaxhibdtbnaqbhdn
    srezcqzv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/Intermediat
    eBuildFilesPath/Pods.build/Release-iphoneos/agora_rtc_engine.build/Objects-n
    ormal/arm64/CallApiMethodCallHandler.o
    /Users/sajad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.1/ios/C
    lasses/CallApiMethodCallHandler.mm normal arm64 objective-c++
    com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'agora_rtc_engine'
    from project 'Pods')
    In file included from
    /Users/sajad/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/agora_rtc_engine-5.1.1/ios/C
    lasses/AgoraTextureViewFactory.mm:3:
    /Users/sajad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ecujwaxhibdtbnaqbhdn
    srezcqzv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProduc
    tsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/AgoraIrisRTC_iOS/AgoraRtcWr
    apper.framework/Headers/iris_video_processor.h:77:13: warning: parameter
    'uid' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
       * @param uid The user ID you want to cache.
                ^~~
    /Users/sajad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ecujwaxhibdtbnaqbhdn
    srezcqzv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProduc
    tsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/AgoraIrisRTC_iOS/AgoraRtcWr
    apper.framework/Headers/iris_video_processor.h:77:13: note: did you mean
    'config'?
       * @param uid The user ID you want to cache.
                ^~~
                config
    /Users/sajad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ecujwaxhibdtbnaqbhdn
    srezcqzv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProduc
    tsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/AgoraIrisRTC_iOS/AgoraRtcWr
    apper.framework/Headers/iris_video_processor.h:78:13: warning: parameter
    'channel_id' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
       * @param channel_id The channel ID.
                ^~~~~~~~~~
    /Users/sajad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-ecujwaxhibdtbnaqbhdn
    srezcqzv/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/BuildProduc
    tsPath/Release-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/AgoraIrisRTC_iOS/AgoraRtcWr
    apper.framework/Headers/iris_video_processor.h:78:13: note: did you mean
    'config'?
       * @param channel_id The channel ID.
                ^~~~~~~~~~

/// lots of warning logs


    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/73/dmwgl2ks3j19zj0n43l_1mkh0000gn/T/flutter_tools.czQYfU/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir0ORaS7/temporary_xcresult_bundle
```

#### What I've tried

- flutter clean
- Cleaning Xcode derived data
- Updating flutter to 3.0.1
- Reimporting `GoogleService-Info.plist`
- Removing `Pods`, `Podfile.lock`
- Updating IOS minimum version to 13
- `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi`
- pod install, pod deintegrate, pod update
- Updating firebase configuration using `flutterfire_cli` and adding a new flutter app in firebase
- Adding `platform` package to pubspec

#### Environment

- Cpu M1
- Xcode 13.1